# Значения из одного массива вставить в ключи второго

Tags: php, массивы

День добрый! Подскажите пожалуйста, как значения из второго массива вставить вместо ключей первого? чтобы на выходе получилось вместо:

```
[1] => Array
            (
                [3] => Резисторы
                [5] => Варисторы
                [6] => Светодиоды
            )
    [Плата 1] => Array
            (
                [3] => Резисторы
                [5] => Варисторы
                [6] => Светодиоды
            )
```

Получился такой массив:

```
Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [3] => Резисторы
                [5] => Варисторы
                [6] => Светодиоды
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [4] => Резисторы
                [7] => Теристоры
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [9] => Конденсаторы
            )

    )
    Array
    (
        [1] => Плата 1
        [2] => Плата 2
        [8] => Плата 3
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для этого имеется функция  [`array_combine()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-combine.php)

первым параметром передаете массив ключей, воторым массив значений. получаете искомое

*в предположении, что порядок исходных ключей двух массивов у вас соответствует друг другу, а не то что в первом 1-2-8 а во втором 8-2-1. в противном случае, можно отсортировать массив по ключам. Либо собрать руками*

Comment: Благодарю. На первый взгляд всё получилось.